# _Token was not found in request data in CakePHP 4

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I have some issue with a simple signup function in cakephp 4,
I enabled the FormProtection component and it return "
_Token was not found in request data."

The token is already generated but I don't know why the controller cannot detect it

```
<?= $this->Form->create($user,['class' => '']) ?>
<?= $this->Flash->render('signup') ?>
<div class="inp-row">
<label for="">Full Name</label>
<?= $this->Form->input('name',["placeholder"=>"Your full name",'label'=>false,'required'=>true,'class' => '']) ?>
</div>
<div class="inp-row">
<label for="">Email Address</label>
<?= $this->Form->input('username',["placeholder"=>"Your email address",'label'=>false,'required'=>true,'type'=>'email','class' => '']) ?>
</div>
<div class="inp-row">
<label for="">Password</label>
<?= $this->Form->input('password',["placeholder"=>"Type your password",'label'=>false,'id'=>"pass_change" ,'required'=>true,'type'=>'password','class' => '']) ?>
</div>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Sign up'));?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

Function signup

```
$user = $this->Users->newEmptyEntity();
if ($this->request->is('post')) {

$user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->getData());
 if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
 $this->Flash->success(__("Your account has been created successfully."), [ 'key' => 'signup']);
        }

    }
$this->set('user', $user);


2020-05-05 23:48:32 Error: [Cake\Http\Exception\BadRequestException] `_Token` was not found in request data. in xxxxxx/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/Component/FormProtectionComponent.php on line 141
Stack Trace:
- xxxxxx/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/Component/FormProtectionComponent.php:95
- xxxxxx/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Event/EventManager.php:309
- xxxxxx/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Event/EventManager.php:286
- xxxxxx/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Event/EventDispatcherTrait.php:92
- xxxxxx/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/Controller.php:569
- xxxxxx/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/ControllerFactory.php:72
- xxxxxx/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/BaseApplication.php:229
- xxxxxx/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:77
- xxxxxx/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Middleware/BodyParserMiddleware.php:164
- xxxxxx/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:73
- xxxxxx/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:77
- xxxxxx/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Middleware/CsrfProtectionMiddleware.php:137
- xxxxxx/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:73
- xxxxxx/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:58
- xxxxxx/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Middleware/RoutingMiddleware.php:162
- xxxxxx/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:73
- xxxxxx/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Middleware/AssetMiddleware.php:68
- xxxxxx/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:73
- xxxxxx/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Middleware/ErrorHandlerMiddleware.php:119
- xxxxxx/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:73
- xxxxxx/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php:58
- xxxxxx/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Server.php:90
- xxxxxx/webroot/index.php:40
```

Comment: Whenever you receive an error, please post the _complete_ error message (including filename and line number), and include the related stacktrace (you'll find both in your CakePHP `/logs/`) - thanks! Also are you using the security component too?

Comment: Thank you for your reply , I added the errors log. Yes , I use Auth and Security components too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The security component is deprecated, its features have been extracted into the form protection component, and the HTTPS enforcer middleware. The fact that it's deprecated should probably be presented more prominently in the Cookbook.

Using both, the form protection component and the security component will lead to the error that you're encountering, as both, the security component as well as the form protection component, will remove the `_Token` from the request data once it has been validated, hence one of them will complain about the token not being present.

Long story short, don't use the security component, use only the form protection component. If you were using the security component's require SSL feature, then use the initially mentioned HTTPS enforcer middleware instead.

See also

- **[Cookbook > 4.0 Migration Guide > Deprecations > Component](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/appendices/4-0-migration-guide.html#component)**
- **[Cookbook > Middleware > HTTPS Enforcer Middleware](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/middleware.html#https-enforcer-middleware)**

Comment: Thank you , I disabled the Security component and added HTTPS enforcer middleware but the https redirection is not working,  it return an error : "Bad Request" for http request

Comment: @devlogi Sounds like you've possibly misconfigured it, and disabled redirects.

Comment: I added this line   ->add(new HttpsEnforcerMiddleware([ 'HttpsEnforcerMiddleware' => true ])) in src/Application.php

Comment: 2020-05-06 14:43:13 Error: [Cake\Http\Exception\BadRequestException] Bad Request in xxxxxxx/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/Component/FormProtectionComponent.php on line 141
Stack Trace:
- xxxxxxx/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/Component/FormProtectionComponent.php:95
- xxxxxxx/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Event/EventManager.php:309
- xxxxxxx/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Event/EventManager.php:286

Comment: @devlogi The error stems from the form protection component, which means the token didn't match. It's rather unrelated to the initial problem, so you should probably open a new question, where you have more place to add details, like what kind of request you're doing exactly, possibly your form, the data being sent, the complete stacktrace, etc. If you have debug mode enabled, then the error page might also have additional information.